Copy newly created files along with the sub-directories
I want to copy only the newly created files in Directory A which has many sub-directories. I am able to find the newly created files using the Find command, but when they are getting copied into Folder B, the files are being copied individually without the sub-directories that they are in Folder A.
I am using the command
find /source/directory/path -ctime -1 -type f exec cp {} /destination/directory/path \;


You can use a combination of find and cpio, as described in the EXAMPLES section of man cpio:

The cpio command is traditionally used to copy file hierarchies in
conjunction with the find(1) command. The first example here simply
copies all files from src to dest:
find src | cpio -pmud dest


In your case it would be
cd /source/directory/path
find . -ctime -1 -type f | cpio -pmud /destination/directory/path

cpio is called with the following options:

 -p      Pass-through.  Read a list of filenames from standard input and
         copy the files to the specified directory.

 -m, --preserve-modification-time
         (i and p modes) Set file modification time on created files to
         match those in the source.

 -u, --unconditional
         (i and p modes) Unconditionally overwrite existing files.
         Ordinarily, an older file will not overwrite a newer file on
         disk.

 -d, --make-directories
         (i and p modes) Create directories as necessary.


Based on this answer on SuperUser:
cd /source/directory/path
find . -ctime -1 -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'cp {} /destination/directoy/`dirname {}`/' \;

Run it with echo instead of cp first to make sure the destination path is correct.
But rsync may be the better tool for this, it would also automatically create new directories if required.
